# Creating a textbox using form_for

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

New to rails, I've been trying to create a text box using form_for since I have multiple inputs in my form,

Currently my site looks like this
[image]

Can someone help me align the box to the center, and possibly put the comments on the top left corner beside the box

Code looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
 <%= form_for(:static_pages,url: about_path, :html =>{:class => 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
 <fieldset>
 <div class = "center form-group">
     <%= f.label :name, :class => "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
     <div class = "col-sm-10">
       <%= f.text_field :name , :class => "form-control" %>
     </div>
   </div>

 <div class = "center form-group">
     <%= f.label :email, :class => "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
     <div class = "col-sm-10">
       <%= f.text_field :email , :class => "form-control" %>
     </div>
   </div>

 <div class = "center form-group">
    <%= f.label :comments, :class => "col-sm2 control-label" %>
    <div class = "col-sm-10">
     <%= text_area_tag 'comment', nil,rows: 10, cols: 60, class: 'comment_input'%>
    </div>
 </div>

<div class = "center form-actions">
  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
</div>
 </fieldset>
<%end%>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Sorry as you can see, I'm pretty bad with html too. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: change: <%= f.label :comments, :class => "col-sm2 control-label", :style => "float: left" %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure that you want to align all input fields at same level..

Here is the css code you have to implement and I hope everything will be perfect.

```
.center form-group{overflow:hidden; clear:left;padding: 5px;}
label{float:left;line-height: 21px;width: 120px;}
.col-sm-10(width: 120px;border: 1px solid #D1D1D1;border-radius: 2px; color: #4D4D4D;width: 200px;)
```

Regards,